# Untrimming trimmed ribbon control

Tags: development, ribbon

My question is straight forward, how do i programmatically untrim the trimmed control on the Ribbon?

So if this happens:

```
 SPRibbon current = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            if (current == null)
                return;
            current.TrimById("Ribbon.Read");
```

How do i untrim it, somewhere in the code?

How do i use method 
SPRibbon.TrimById(string id, string visibilityContext)?

Why makeTabAvailable() doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible - the SPRibbon.TrimById operation is not reversible! Refelcting the method reveals that the specified id is added to a private ArrayList in the SPRibbon class. There is no corresponding SPRibbon.UntrimById method. You will need to find a way to avoid the trimming in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

public void HideRibbonButton()

{
//if this is a System.Web.UI.Page

SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this);

ribbon.TrimById(“Ribbon.DocLibListForm.Edit.Actions.DeleteItem”);

}

Hide Groupribbon.TrimById(“Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout”);

Check Link

http://sampathnarsingam.blogspot.in/2012/05/sharepoint-2010-hide-ribbon-buttons.html

Comment: I know how to hide (trim) buttons, i need to reveal them, make them visible again!